# How to fill form fields based on other fields values using AJAX

Tags: 7, forms

I have 3 fields. On blur on any of them I want to look for empty ones - if blurred one has value and any of the others does not, I want to copy value.

Obtaining value is easy, simply `$form_state['triggering_element']['#value']`, but setting it elsewhere gets tricky.

Changing `$form['item']['#default_value']` does not work if field is empty after user's edit. Changing `$form['item']['#value']` makes Drupal ignore any further user input. Changing `$form_state['values']` seems to do nothing. What is the correct approach that should work? When I'll know that, I'll be able to debug.

Comment: Have you tried `$form_state['input']['item'] = '...'`?

Comment: @Clive - right. Case of a hole in memory it seems. Do you think it's better to delete it or format it properly and leave it?

Comment: Leave it open I'd say. I didn't put that in as an answers as I've never taken the time to find out _why_ that method works and others don't. If you could a bit of example code to the question and answe it yourself with exactly what you did to make it work this could very useful to future visitors

Comment: My code now looks like `$form_state['input']["properties"][$property_machine_name]['parameters']['parameters'][$language->idLanguage]['choices']` - it'll take some time to clear it ;) But I guess I should, at evening. Note - 'parameters' are doubled becouse of you, @Clive, and one of your answers ;)

Comment: Oh dear, what nonsense have I been spouting now? ;)

Comment: @Clive no nonsense, it's just a quick and apparently dirty implementation of [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75721/how-to-hide-empty-fieldset-but-leave-prefix-and-suffix-in-place)

Comment: $form['item']['#default_value'] must work. Might you can explain what did you mean "does not work if field is empty after user's edit." ?

Comment: @milkovsky if field got emptied by an user, it's no longer considered default value, but user provided one, and thus changing `#dafault_value` has no effect at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was, as Clive suggested, to simply use:

```
$form_state['input']['item'] = '...';
```

For elements that got replaced by AJAX, works like a charm.

If that's not enough, using [AJAX commands](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7) might be needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this workaround did the trick. 
Basically you clear up `$form_state['input']` value **and rebuild the form**.

Form builder:

```
<?php 
$form['test'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield', 
  '#title' => t('Test'),
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'my_test_callback_func',
    'wrapper' => 'edit-test2',
    'progress' => array(
      'message' => '',
      'type' => 'throbber',
    ),
  ),
);

$form['test2'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield', 
  '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-test2">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>', 
  '#title' => t('Test2'),
);
?>
```

**Ajax callback function:
This is the trickier part.**

```
<?php 
function my_test_callback_func($form, &$form_state) {
  unset($form_state['input']['test2'], $form_state['values']['test2']);
  $form['test2']['#default_value'] = 'Auto Filled!';
  $form_state['input']['test2'] = 'Auto Filled!';
  return form_builder($form['#id'], $form['test2'], $form_state);
}
?>
```

We unset the user input (or check if it's empty), set a default value and then rebuild the form.